# springboot：org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Data conversion error converting "xxx@xx.com"

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2, mybatis

I am using mybatis generator to generate mapper, dao.

Here are attributes in dao

```
private Integer id;
private String userEmail;
private Integer code;
private LocalDateTime expire;
private Boolean status;
```

I add a record in the h2 database, it returns true, the database does have this record.

```
I implemented a method in resetPwdMapper.java
@Insert("insert into reset_pwd(email,code,expire,status) values(#{email},#{code},#{expire},#{status})")
int addCode(ResetPwd record);
```

ResetPwdService.java

```
public boolean addRecord(ResetPwd resetPwd){
    return resetPwdMapper.addCode(resetPwd)==1;
}
```

Test.java

```
String email="xxx",
Integer code=11111,
LocalDateTime expireTime = LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(5);
ResetPwd resetPwd = new ResetPwd(email,code, expireTime,true);
boolean a = resetPwdService.addRecord(resetPwd);  //a is true, this shows I definitely can access the database
```

however, when I try to get records, it shows an exception.

```
List<ResetPwd> records = resetPwdMapper.selectByExample(null);

 2020-11-13 15:37:23.288 ERROR 22240 --- [nio-8081-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : 
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request 
processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Error 
attempting to get column 'EMAIL' from result set.  Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Data 
conversion error converting "xxxx@xx.com" [22018-200]
; Data conversion error converting "xxxx@xx.com" [22018-200]; nested exception is 
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLDataException: Data conversion error converting "xxxx@xx.com" [22018-200]] with 
root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "xxxx@xx.com"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at org.h2.value.Value.convertToInt(Value.java:982) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:806) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:737) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
at org.h2.value.Value.getInt(Value.java:623) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.getInt(JdbcResultSet.java:352) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getInt(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
at org.apache.ibatis.type.IntegerTypeHandler.getNullableResult(IntegerTypeHandler.java:37) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at org.apache.ibatis.type.IntegerTypeHandler.getNullableResult(IntegerTypeHandler.java:26) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.getResult(BaseTypeHandler.java:81) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createUsingConstructor(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:671) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createByConstructorSignature(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:654) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createResultObject(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:618) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createResultObject(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:591) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getRowValue(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:397) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValuesForSimpleResultMap(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:354) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValues(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:328) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:301) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSets(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:194) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:65) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:79) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:63) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:324) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:156) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:109) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:83) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:147) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:140) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:426) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.selectList(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:223) ~[mybatis-spring-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:147) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:80) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:93) ~[mybatis-3.5.3.jar:3.5.3]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy140.selectByExample(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.csi4900.hyx.caev_web_project.controller.AuthController.resetPwd(AuthController.java:156) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_202]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_202]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_202]
```

mybastis version： mybatis-spring-boot-starter 2.1.1;
h2 database version: 1.4.200;
I am very curious why it shows numberFormatException.

Comment: In your request, maybe you should try to add #{email} surroudended by quotes as it is a String ?

Comment: I can insert record into the database, which means no quote are fine. Also, selectByExample method is generated by mybatis generator, so I dont think that is   quotes problem.

Comment: Your application tries to read a character string value with `ResultSet.getInt()` method. It looks like it queries the `email` column, but thinks that it is an `id` column.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
My problem was column order in the Schema and the Pojo class were a mismatch.

To solve the issue, u can remove the constructor or Update its parameters to match the order of the Table Schema.

My table schema was :-

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NOTES (
    noteid INT PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
    notehead VARCHAR(20),
    notedescription VARCHAR (1000),
    userid INT,
    foreign key (userid) references USERS(userid)
);
```

my Pojo class constructtor was :-

```
public Note(Integer noteId, Integer userId, String noteHead, String noteDescription) {
        this.noteId = noteId;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.noteHead = noteHead;
        this.noteDescription = noteDescription;

    }
```

So when retrieving the data, mybatis thinks that Id value is the description.

Answer (score 0):

1. "userEmail" field name is not matching. In query u have written "email" whereas in POJO calss
   its "userEmail".

This could be the reason.